# Show/Hide Requires a Double-click

Tags: javascript, html, css, show-hide

I'm writing a basic show/hide function that displays a block of content and changes some text from "Show More Benefits" to "Show Less Benefits" (and vice versa).

For some reason though, when I click "Show More Benefits" for the first time, it requires two clicks to run. Afterwards, it alternates back and forth just fine with one click.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="content" id="content"><br>
<p><span class="benefit-stat">$2B</span> lorem</p>
<p><span class="benefit-stat">$2B</span> ipsum</p>
<p><span class="benefit-stat">$100</span> ipsum</p>
<p><span class="benefit-stat">32%</span> ipsum</p>
</div>
<p class="benefits-drop" id="text" onclick="showHide()">See More Benefits</p>
<script>
function showHide(c,t) {
  var c = document.getElementById("content");
  var t = document.getElementById("text");
  if (c.style.display === "none") {
    c.style.display = "block";
    t.innerHTML = 'See Less Benefits';
  } else {
    t.innerHTML = 'See More Benefits';
    c.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Any reason as to why this is happening? How would I go about fixing it?

Comment: `console.log(c.style.display, c.style.display === "none")`

Comment: Uh: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined - (then the very long id, as this is a hubspot page)

Comment: So means it can not find the element that you referenced

Comment: Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you need to click twice:

`element.style.display` refers to **inline styles only**.

Initially, your elements do not have a `style`-attribute. As a result, `element.style.display` returns the empty String:

```js
function showHide(c,t) {
  var c = document.getElementById("content");
  var t = document.getElementById("text");
  console.log("c.style.display is:" + c.style.display);
  if (c.style.display === "none") {
    c.style.display = "block";
    t.innerHTML = 'See Less Benefits';
  } else {
    t.innerHTML = 'See More Benefits';
    c.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="content"><br>
<p><span class="benefit-stat">$2B</span> lorem</p>
<p><span class="benefit-stat">$2B</span> ipsum</p>
<p><span class="benefit-stat">$100</span> ipsum</p>
<p><span class="benefit-stat">32%</span> ipsum</p>
</div>
<p class="benefits-drop" id="text" onclick="showHide()">See More Benefits</p>
```

Bad but simple solution:

Add the `style="display: block"` to your initial HTML:

```js
function showHide(c,t) {
  var c = document.getElementById("content");
  var t = document.getElementById("text");
  console.log("c.style.display is:" + c.style.display);
  if (c.style.display === "none") {
    c.style.display = "block";
    t.innerHTML = 'See Less Benefits';
  } else {
    t.innerHTML = 'See More Benefits';
    c.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="content" style="display: none"><br>
<p><span class="benefit-stat">$2B</span> lorem</p>
<p><span class="benefit-stat">$2B</span> ipsum</p>
<p><span class="benefit-stat">$100</span> ipsum</p>
<p><span class="benefit-stat">32%</span> ipsum</p>
</div>
<p class="benefits-drop" id="text" onclick="showHide()">See More Benefits</p>
```

Better solution:

Instead of toggling `style.display` between `none` and `block`, instead toggle the universal attribute `hidden`:

```js
function showHide() {
  const c = document.getElementById("content");
  const t = document.getElementById("text");
  
  t.textContent = c.hidden ? 'See Less Benefits' : 'See More Benefits';
  c.hidden = !c.hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="content" hidden><br>
<p><span class="benefit-stat">$2B</span> lorem</p>
<p><span class="benefit-stat">$2B</span> ipsum</p>
<p><span class="benefit-stat">$100</span> ipsum</p>
<p><span class="benefit-stat">32%</span> ipsum</p>
</div>
<p class="benefits-drop" id="text" onclick="showHide()">See More Benefits</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, with transition animation:

```
    <button class="Show">Show</button>
<button class="Hide">Hide</button>
<div id="target"></div>

<style>
.Hide{display:none;}
</style>

<script>
$('.Show').click(function() {
    $('#target').show(500);
    $('.Show').hide(0);
    $('.Hide').show(0);
});
$('.Hide').click(function() {
    $('#target').hide(500);
    $('.Show').show(0);
    $('.Hide').hide(0);
});
$('.toggle').click(function() {
    $('#target').toggle('fast');
});
</script>
```

Comment: I highly advise to stay away from jQuery or any other libraries until your native Javascript and knowledge of the native DOM API is worth calling fluid.